# multiple reviews on multiple models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create multiple reviews system on anything like news, articles, blogs etc.
    Review module should be independent so I can put this anywhere on my website.

I have also created review, blogs, news, articles models

suppose:

- blogs has_many reviews
- news has_many reviews
- articles has_many reviews

but problem is this i can put this only for blogs but not for others models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn about polymorphic associations

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations